Why TypeScript is allowing property that doesn't exists in type
With the following types, I'm trying to create a list of navigation links. Which can be a link or groups of links in the list (array)
type NavLink = {
  label: string;
  href: string;
  icon?: string;
  permissions?: string[];
};

type NavLinkGroup = Omit<NavLink, 'href' | 'permissions'> & {
  href: NavLink[];
}

const links: (NavLink | NavLinkGroup)[] = [
  { // ----------------------------------------> NavLink
    label: 'a nav link',
    href: 'http://localhost:8000',
    permissions: ['can_do_things']
  },
  { // ---------------------------------------> NavLinkGroup
    label: 'group',
    permissions: ['what?!'], // why this is not generates error? as it should be "NavLinkGroup" by "href" porop
    href: [
      {
        label: 'link to a page',
        href: 'http://link.to/website',
      }
    ],
  },
];

console.log(links);

Playground link
I want to know that 2nd item in the links allowing permissions It should be NavLinkGroup thus it should throw an error about permissions

TS types are open, not closed. Non-discriminated unions like NavLinkGroup don't get excess property checking on types that appear in at least one member of the union. See the above-linked q/a for more information.

Thank you for the info. Is there any way to get the expected outcome with TS?

Yes, you can "exclusify" the union as mentioned in the answer to the other question. In your example it looks like this playground link.

Actually, I've tried this before, this still suggests permissions property and allows undefined as value. Looks like a lacking of TS. Isn't it?
